# How to declare a variable of a custom type (like time.Date) in go?

Tags: object, go, variables, declare

I am trying to create this block of code:

```golang
var nextWorkday time.Date
// var nextWorkday *time.Date // neither works
yyyy, mm, dd := now.Date()
goalTime, _ := time.ParseDuration(fmt.Sprintf("%fh", *goal))
goalSeconds := int(goalTime.Seconds())
if date.Weekday() != time.Friday { // wait till the next workday (7am + difference)
    nextWorkday = time.Date(yyyy, mm, dd+1, 7, 0, 0+goalSeconds, 0, now.Location())
} else {
    nextWorkday = time.Date(yyyy, mm, dd+3, 7, 0, 0+goalSeconds, 0, now.Location())
}
time.Sleep(nextWorkday)
```

The important breaking point is already the first line. I do not know how to declare a new variable of a custom type. Right now I get the error:
`time.Date is not a type`

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try `time.Time` instead of `time.Date`.

Comment: Thank you! This did already work :) 
Seems a bit confusing to me that time.Date actually is a time.Time object

Comment: Should I post the official answer or do you want?^^

Comment: @Tillus always take a look at the doc of the package you are using. That will give you a clear idea about what type does the package provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `time.Date` type in the standard [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time) package. There is however a [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) type which represents a time instant, "including" date.

[`time.Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date) is a function which constructs a `time.Time` value from the provided date and time fields.